# How do you get a section of a report to be visible if there is no data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I am replacing a report that is currently done in Excel. However, I can't figure out a trick to have an entire section remain if there is no data.

This is a Budget vs actual report as an example. This Category has no budget for Full-time employees (hence no data in the data set.))

[image: Example]

Thanks for your suggestions.

My current effort is to force a null row to come through in the query.

Comment: Test for this in your dataset and append some blank/zero/null values as applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with breaking the 3 possible pieces into CTEs and outer applying to the parts I didn't want to exclude.

```
Select *
from (values('Personnel','Full-Time')) a(Cat,SubCat)
outer apply cte_FT

union all

Select *
from (values('Personnel','Part-Time')) a(Cat,SubCat)
outer apply cte_PT

union all

Select *
from (values('Non-Personnel','')) a(Cat,SubCat)
outer apply cte_NP
```

The result of this data set allows you to build the above report.